# How to distinguish between postpaid and prepaid network operator programmatically

Tags: android

I need to know, is there any API or code available through which I can distinguish between pospaid and prepaid network?

Comment: No context? What have you tried? Is this a custom module?

Comment: @JosiahHester out of curiosity, is it really possible to find out the network type (post or pre paid)? AFAIK, it is configured on the Network provider end, and no information is sent to mobile device.

Comment: @AtifFarrukh is right. I also think that it is not possible.